# How to get the parent name if chid taxonomy term id is known?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How to get the parent name if child taxonomy term id is known??

Comment: How can someone answer if the Drupal version is unknown?

Answer (score 3):

- Drupal 5.x: Taxonomy_get_parents()
- Drupal 6.x: Taxonomy_get_parents()
- Drupal 7.x: Taxonomy_get_parents()
- Drupal 8.0.x: TermStorage::loadParents()
- Drupal 8.1.x: TermStorage::loadParents()
- Drupal 8.2.x: TermStorage::loadParents()